# Facing error while setting the ringtone permanently

Tags: android

I want to change my call ringtone permanently which will be invoked
from SD card and that ringtone should work more then one time.

I am using the following code:

```
RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(getApplicationContext(), RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, Note);
```

Comment: what kind of error you are facing post here logs

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeExeptions:Unable to start activity ComponntInfo{com.securityExeption:PermitionDenial:writing com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider uri content://settings/system from pid=1895, uid=10056 requires android.permission.WRITE.SETTINGS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `android.permission.WRITE.SETTINGS` permission to your manifest file as your exception specifies that